# Sum of rows based on index with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array composed of 2D vectors and a 1D array of indices.

How can I add / sumvthe rows of the 2D array **that share the same index**, using numpy?

Example:

```
arr = np.array([[48, -51], [-15, -55], [26, -49], [-13, -17], [-67,  -7], [23, -48], [-29, -64], [37,  68]])
idx = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])

#desired output
array([[48, -51],
       [11, -104],
       [-80, -24],
       [-6, -112],
       [ 37, 68]])
```

Notice how the original array `arr` is of shape (8, 2), and the result of the operation is (5, 2).

Comment: Are numbers in `idx` always in ascending order?

Comment: Not sure about the "always", but most of the time certainly.

Comment: This is not a cumulative sum, but a regular one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indices are not always grouped, apply [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) first:

```
order = np.argsort(idx)
```

You can compute the locations of the sums using [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) followed by [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to get the indices. We'll also prepend zero and shift everything by 1:

```
breaks = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([1], np.diff(idx[order])))
```

`breaks` can now be used as an argument to [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
result = np.add.reduceat(arr[order, :], breaks, axis=0)
```

If the indices are already grouped, you don't need to use `order` at all:

```
breaks = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([1], np.diff(idx)))
result = np.add.reduceat(arr, breaks, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` for the purpose:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(idx).sum().to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([[  48,  -51],
       [  11, -104],
       [ -80,  -24],
       [  -6, -112],
       [  37,   68]])
```